# Why does the size of the persistence context affect query time in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  Foo foo = dao.loadFooById(i);
}
//dao.getEntityManager().clear();
Bar bar = dao.loadBarById(0);
```

As it stands this code would take 200ms for the `loadBarById(0)` method.  If I uncomment the commented line it takes <1 ms.  There is no eager relationship between Foo entities and Bar entities.  Why would the size of the persistence context affect the load time of an entity?

FYI: I am aware I will suffer all kinds of other issues having a large persistence context and that I should be managing it by operating on batches of entities.  This is just for my own understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PersistenceContext ( Hibernate Session ) is cache for all  kinds of values and proxies. if transactions are active, rollback informations are also stored somewhere.   Clearing persistence manager / session makes cache work faster.

You need to take care about amount of objects loaded in single session or suffer performance issues.